# assembly program that have two integer array X and Y of size 10 where Y contains: one if the element in X is positive zero if that element is < = 0

Tags: assembly, x86-16, signed, emu8086

assembly program that have two integer array X and Y of size 10 where Y contains: one if the  element in X is positive zero if that element is < = 0
I wrote this but it doesn`t match the solution that I want and I can enter for infinite numbers, not just a 10 number

```
.MODEL SMALL
.DATA
x db 10 dup ( ? )
y db 10 dup ( ? )
.CODE
mov si,offset x
mov di,offset y
main1:
mov ah,01h
int 21h
mov bh,0
mov bl,al 
sub bl,30h
cmp bl,0
ja l1
jmp l2
l1:
 mov ah , 1
mov [si] , al
inc si
jmp l3

l2 : mov ah , 0
mov [di] , al
inc di
jmp l3

     

l3 :

mov dl,al
MOV AH, 02h
INT 21H
cmp si,10
je l4
cmp di,10
je l4
jmp main1

l4 : 
.EXIT
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You have applied some of my suggestions from [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69831134/check-positive-number-assembly8086/69833278#69833278), but ignored others!

Your use of `sub bl,30h` implies that you expect the input to be a digit [0,9]. No digit is ever going to be negative!

```
.MODEL SMALL
.DATA
x db 10 dup ( ? )
y db 10 dup ( ? )
.CODE                <<<< Where's initializing DS ?
mov si,offset x
mov di,offset y
main1:
mov ah,01h
int 21h
mov bh,0             <<<< (*) Where's storing the original value in the x array ?
mov bl,al 
sub bl,30h
cmp bl,0
ja l1                <<<< Has to be SIGNED comparison, use JGE
jmp l2
l1:
 mov ah , 1
mov [si] , al        <<<< The 1 is in AH, use AH instead of AL
inc si               <<<< Store in the y array and increment DI
jmp l3

l2 : mov ah , 0
mov [di] , al        <<<< The 0 is in AH, use AH instead of AL
inc di
jmp l3

     

l3 :

mov dl,al            <<<< The 1 or 0 is still in AH, use AH instead of AL
MOV AH, 02h          <<<< Add 48 to DL before printing
INT 21H
cmp si,10            <<<< Could work if (*)
je l4
cmp di,10            <<<< Will never work and is redundant
je l4
jmp main1

l4 : 
.EXIT
END
```

### A good solution

Since inputting a single **digit** will never result in a negative number, use the solution from my previous answer.
Next code, just like yours, inputs a single character from the keyboard and treats its ASCII code as the byte you want to store in the x array. For negative bytes you should input extended ASCII's. Use <kbd>Alt</kbd> followed by a number up to 255.

```
ORG 256
 xor  bx, bx
again:
 mov  ah, 01h      ; DOS.GetCharacter
 int  21h          ; -> AL
 mov  x[bx], al
 mov  ah, 255
 shl  ax, 1
 not  ah
 mov  y[bx], ah    ; 1 for positive, 0 for negative
 inc  bx
 mov  dl, ah
 add  dl, 48
 mov  ah, 02h
 int  21h
 cmp  bx, 10
 jb   again
 mov  ax, 4C00h
 int  21h

x db 10 dup (0)
y db 10 dup (0)
END
```

### A correct solution

If you insist, your code with correction but sadly not improved in any way:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.DATA
x db 10 dup ( ? )
y db 10 dup ( ? )
.CODE
mov ax, data
mov ds, ax
mov si,offset x  ; De facto SI=0
mov di,offset y
main1:
mov ah,01h
int 21h
sub al, 48     ; From character to number [0,9]
mov [si], al
inc si
cmp al,0
jge l1     ; For positive
jmp l2     ; For negative
l1:
 mov ah , 1
mov [di] , ah
inc di
jmp l3

l2 : mov ah , 0
mov [di] , ah
inc di
jmp l3

     

l3 :

mov dl,ah
add dl, 48
MOV AH, 02h
INT 21H
cmp si,10
je l4
jmp main1

l4 : 
.EXIT
END
```